# Is there a way to fix the code as the for loop is coming up as unreachable?

Tags: java

Is there a clear syntax error in my code below as it says all the code from the for loop down is unreachable?

```
   if(!(varName.charAt(0)=='_'||(varName.charAt(0)>='A'&& varName.charAt(0)<='Z')||(varName.charAt(0)>='a'&& varName.charAt(0)<='z'))) {

 }return u;
for(int i = 0; i<varName.length(); i++) {
 if(!(varName.charAt(i)=='_'||(varName.charAt(i)>='A'&& varName.charAt(i)<='Z')||(varName.charAt(i)>='a'&& varName.charAt(i)<='z')||(varName.charAt(i)>='0'&& varName.charAt(i)<='9'))) {

 return u;
}else return true;
```

}}

Comment: The return statement is after the if block so it always returns so yes the rest is unreachable

Comment: Did you intend the first `return u;` to be inside the if statement? As it is, it is always executed.

Comment: Please use an IDE and use its auto formatter to get a better understanding how the different statements interact and why they do not make sense right now.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you placed `return u;` statement after if block making following lines unreachable.